# [[FATAL]] [[DBT-06103]] The port (5,500) is already in use

Tags: oracle, linux, oracle-xe, centos-7, oracle-18c

I am trying to install oracle 18c XE on CentOS 7. I have opened the ports:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=1521/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=1630/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=3938/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=1830/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=1849/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=1158/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5500/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5519/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5520/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5539/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5540/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5559/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5560/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5579/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5580/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5599/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5600/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5620/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5640/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5659/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5660/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5679/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

When trying `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c  configure` the following error is displayed:

```
Specify a password to be used for database accounts. Oracle recommends that the password entered should be at least 8 characters in length, contain at least 1 uppercase character, 1 lower case character and 1 digit [0-9]. Note that the same password will be used for SYS, SYSTEM and PDBADMIN accounts:
Confirm the password:

Passwords do not match.  Enter the password:
Confirm the password:
Configuring Oracle Listener.
Listener configuration succeeded.
Configuring Oracle Database XE.
[FATAL] [DBT-06103] The port (5,500) is already in use.
   ACTION: Specify a free port.

Database configuration failed. Check logs under '/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca'.
```

I searched and found its due to hostname configuration:

```
[root@linux ~]# cat /etc/hostname
linux.mydomain.com

[root@linux ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain 
163.173.24.179  linux.mydomain.com

[root@linux ~]# hostname
linux.mydomain.com

[root@linux ~]# hostname -f
linux.mydomain.com
```

**UPDATE-1**

```
[root@linux oracle]# grep -w 5500 /etc/services
fcp-addr-srvr1  5500/tcp                # fcp-addr-srvr1
fcp-addr-srvr1  5500/udp                # fcp-addr-srvr1
```

**UPDATE-2:**

```
[root@linux oracle]# sudo nmap -sT -O localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-06-03 20:57 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0014s latency).
Not shown: 986 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
25/tcp   open  smtp
53/tcp   open  domain
106/tcp  open  pop3pw
110/tcp  open  pop3
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
143/tcp  open  imap
465/tcp  open  smtps
993/tcp  open  imaps
995/tcp  open  pop3s
1521/tcp open  oracle
3306/tcp open  mysql
8009/tcp open  ajp13
8443/tcp open  https-alt
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 3.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3
OS details: Linux 3.7 - 3.9
Network Distance: 0 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.38 seconds
[root@linux oracle]# sudo nmap -sU -O 163.172.24.189

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-06-03 20:58 CEST
Nmap scan report for linux.mydomain.com (163.172.24.189)
Host is up (0.000048s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT    STATE         SERVICE
53/udp  open          domain
111/udp open          rpcbind
776/udp open|filtered wpages
Warning: OSScan results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open and 1 closed port
Device type: webcam|general purpose|phone|storage-misc
Running: AXIS Linux 2.6.X, Linux 2.6.X, ZyXEL embedded
OS CPE: cpe:/h:axis:210a_network_camera cpe:/h:axis:211_network_camera cpe:/o:axis:linux_kernel:2.6 cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6 cpe:/o:google:android:2.2 cpe:/h:zyxel:nsa-210
OS details: AXIS 210A or 211 Network Camera (Linux 2.6), Linux 2.6.14 - 2.6.34, Linux 2.6.17, Linux 2.6.17 (Mandriva), Android 2.2 (Linux 2.6), ZyXEL NSA-210 NAS device
Network Distance: 0 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 7.01 seconds
[root@linux oracle]# sudo nmap -sT -O 163.172.24.189

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-06-03 21:04 CEST
Nmap scan report for linux.mydomain.com (163.172.24.189)
Host is up (0.0014s latency).
Not shown: 986 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
25/tcp   open  smtp
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
106/tcp  open  pop3pw
110/tcp  open  pop3
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
143/tcp  open  imap
443/tcp  open  https
465/tcp  open  smtps
993/tcp  open  imaps
995/tcp  open  pop3s
1521/tcp open  oracle
8443/tcp open  https-alt
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 3.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3
OS details: Linux 3.7 - 3.9
Network Distance: 0 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.38 seconds
```

Please advise where I am making mistake?

Best Regards

Comment: Not sure what a network port in use would have to do with the hostname. You got the error because some other piece of software is already using that port. You can see which using "netstat -an | grep 5500".

Comment: result of # netstat -an | grep 5500
`unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     315500 `

Comment: Port 5500 is for Enterprise Manager (Lite).  It is not needed for running a DB (it can be configured later).  Since port 1521 seems active, it looks the DB was installed; just EM failed. See if you can connect to the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short name of your host is missing from  `/etc/hosts`, only the FQDN is there.
It should be:

`163.173.24.179  linux.mydomain.com linux`

`linux` (`hostname -s`) is unreachable due to this.

Comment: Thanks from the bottom of my heart

Comment: thanks you so much, I was missing this prerequisite before launching ora 19 install. This is now running fine.