# [[FATAL]] [[DBT-06103]] The port (5,500) is already in use in Docker Container

Tags: oracle, linux, docker, oracle-19c

I'm trying to use Oracle 19c DB Container for my test cases in Jenkins Job but DB Container is intermittently failing with this error

```
[FATAL] [DBT-06103] The port (5,500) is already in use.
   ACTION: Specify a free port.
```

I referred this answer [[[FATAL]] [[DBT-06103]] The port (5,500) is already in use](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/268437/fatal-dbt-06103-the-port-5-500-is-already-in-use?newreg=335276877b8c4859a5fd41263b960125) but how to achieve this in container where hostname is always dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

The hostname (actually, the container name) is only dynamic if you don't specify one, so -- specify one. – [mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio)